# Accumulate number of VBA function is not working

Tags: vba

I am trying to use VBA function to add up a number's all power result together.

For example if I have 6 as revenue, and have `first=1` and `last=5`, `diff=5-1=4`, then the result should be like `total=6+6^2+6^3+6^4`.

Below is my VBA code and not sure why it is not working and always give me result as 0:

```
Function AC(last, first, revenue)
    diff = last - firs
    For i = 1 To diff
        Count = revenue ^ i
        Total = Total + Count
    Next i
End Function
```

Thanks if anyone can help me

Comment: Scott's answer solves the issue raised in the question, but I'm wondering what answer you are expecting if `last` is 8, `first` is 4 and `revenue` is 6 - are you after 6^1+6^2+6^3+6^4 again (i.e. the same as if `last` was 5 and `first` was 1) or are you really trying to produce 6^4+6^5+6^6+6^7+6^8?

Comment: if last is 8 and first is 4. then diff is 4 and total will be 6+6^2+6^3+6^4

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a value to the Function for it to return a value.  You also have a spelling error on `diff = last - firs` :

```
Function AC(last, first, revenue)

diff = last - first
For i = 1 To diff
    Count = revenue ^ i
    Total = Total + Count
Next i
AC = Total
End Function
```

---

To be safe one should also always declare the variables, and we can do the addition right to the function:

```
Option Explicit

Function AC(ByVal last As Long, ByVal first As Long, ByVal revenue As Double) As Double
Dim diff As Long
Dim i as long
Dim Count as Double
diff = last - first
For i = 1 To diff
    Count = revenue ^ i
    AC = AC + Count
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: I would add `Option Explicit`, as well as explicit visibility and return type for the function, and explicit type for the parameters (all types should be `Double` I think), which should be passed `ByVal`. I'll leave the cryptic/meaningless "AC" identifier uncommented though (oops) ;-)

Comment: @YowE3K yeah, yeah, yeah 8P

Comment: @YowE3k I am on my phone what do you expect.

Comment: I must admit that I don't expect much of people who use phones for accessing the internet.  (My mobile phone isn't even internet-enabled - I just use it as a .... phone!! :D)

Answer (score 0):

With array formula `AC = [sum(6 ^ row(1:4))]` ( `#` is short for `As Double`) :

```
Function AC#(last#, first#, revenue#)
    AC = Evaluate("sum(" & revenue & " ^ row(1:" & last - first & "))")
End Function
```

---

With Excel Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(revenue ^ ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & last - first)))
```

Comment: Thanks, the formula just make thing really simple

Answer (score 0):

Here's a loop-less implementation:

```
Function AC(last, first, revenue)
    If revenue = 1 then AC = last - first: Exit Function
    AC = revenue*((revenue^(last - first) - 1) / (revenue-1))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use this function